# JQuery navbar stuck to bottom rather than above

Tags: jquery, html, css

My navigation bar works fine and as it should. It's initially at the bottom of the page and when you scroll past it then sticks to the top of the page. However I want it to be 75px higher than bottom of the page to begin with. So you can see some of the content below. here is my code (my guess is that because I used window height it won't let me just add -'75px' to the code)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var windowH = $(window).height();
  var stickToBot = windowH - $('.topmenu').outerHeight(true);

  $('.topmenu').css({
    'top': stickToBot + 'px'
  });

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollVal = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (scrollVal > stickToBot) {
      $('.topmenu').css({
        'position': 'fixed',
        'top': '0px'
      });
    } else {
      $('.topmenu').css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'top': stickToBot + 'px'
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#wholesite {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
#header {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #000100;
}
video {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}
.videocontainer {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%
}
.topmenu {
  height: 75px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: block;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wholesite">
  <div id="header">
    <div class="videocontainer">
      <video width="auto" height="500px" autoplay>
        <source src="lbsedited.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
    </div>
    <div>
      <nav>
        <ul class="topmenu">
          <li><a href="player_representation.html">- SERVICES -</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="financial_advice.html">- FINANCIAL ADVICE -</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="index.html">
              <img src="textonly.jpg" alt="" height="71" width="87">
            </a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="property_managment.html">- PROPERTY MANAGEMENT -</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="testimonials.html">- TESTIMONIALS -</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="mainpage">
    <div class="title">
      <h1> About Us </h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

add the -75px in when you are calculating the window height

```
var windowH = $(window).height() -75px;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back to me. When I tried that the top menu doesn't stick to the top of the screen anymore... I tried it with -'75px' though because I got a syntax error without the apostrophes

Comment: did you try with $('.topmenu').css({
        'top': (stickToBot - 75) +'px'

Comment: you will have to adjust the value in the scrollval if function

Comment: I changed it to: 
$(document).ready(function() {
   var windowH = $(window).height() -'75px';
   var stickToBot = windowH - $('.topmenu').outerHeight(true) ;
    
    $('.topmenu').css({'top': (stickToBot -'75') + 'px'});
   
   $(window).scroll(function() {
       var scrollVal = $(this).scrollTop();
        if ( scrollVal > (stickToBot-'75px') ) {
            $('.topmenu').css({'position':'fixed','top' :'0px'});
        } else {
            $('.topmenu').css({'position':'absolute','top': stickToBot +'px' });
        }
    });
 });
but it still doesn't stick

Comment: no leave out the window height bit and just change it in the stick to bottom

Comment: hmm when I do that it is initially in the right place. but then as soon as I scroll down the tiniest bit it jumps back to the bottom and then doesn't stick either

Comment: whats your site address? its a very poor fiddle

Comment: Yeah sorry, I just put up the bits of relevant code and not the whole thing. It's not live at the moment :/